# Is there a way to inverse/inverse an ImmutableMap

Tags: java, guava

Given an `ImmutableMap<K,V>` where values are non-unique, is there a way to invert / inverse / pivot this to an ImmutableMap like collection that allows for multiple keys?

I would assume that it would end up being an `ImmutableSetMultiMap<V,K>`

I was previously using an `ImmutableSetMultiMap<K,V>` but realized that it allowed multiple keys, which could be a possible source of bugs in the future.

This also renders a ImmutableBiMap useless, as there could be non-unique values.

Comment: You want to convert it to Map where the previous values map to the corresponding keys?

Comment: Yes, I realize due to the multiple values that it will likely end up being a multimap of some description, or some other data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ImmutableSetMultimap<Value, Key> inverse = immutableMap.asMultimap().inverse();
```

is, if I understand correctly, what you're looking for.

If you want this as a map, then call `asMap()` on the result, and you'll get a `ImmutableMap<Value,Collection<Key>>`

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want, however I am unable to find the method immutableMap.asMultiMap().

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#asMultimap%28%29

Comment: How do you use @Beta annotated code in guava? also isn't it subject to change?

Comment: Also, (and I'm not sure if this is a major issue) this ends up with a Collection<Key> as opposed to a key, is there any way to ensure that this only has 1 element? or should I somehow make an assertation in the code?

Comment: You use it exactly the same way as a non-annotated method. Beta is only there to signal that the method might change or disappear in the future. The method is there since v14, and Guava is at v18, so I guess there is a good chance for this method to stay. If it doesn't, then you'll look for a replacement when needed.

Comment: Guava has no way to know that your original map has unique values. Let's say your map contains A->1 and B->1. The inverse of this map is 1->[A,B]. If you can guarantee the uniqueness of values, then use a BiMap.

Comment: The original map does not have unique values, it has unique keys,

and I've just seen the error in my logic, thanks.

Comment: In case you were wondering it ended up being a stupid error preventing me from seeing asMultimap. I had pattern instead of this.pattern I'm going to seriously consider never naming parameters after fields in the future.

Comment: If your keys and values were unique, then you could use a `BiMap` (or the immutable flavor), then you can invert it without getting a collection of values.